# OwnCloud does not use alternative config directory

Tags: owncloud

I'd like to run an OwnCloud instance with an alternative configuration directory. The client version is 1.6.2. I use the following command:

```
owncloud --confdir /path/to/owncloud.cfg
```

The always tries to take the default directory to get the configuration and if this is empty it ask me for server address, user name and password and so on and creates a new owncloud.cfg again.

I found some descriptions on the internet where this seems to work, but not on my machine. Does somebody has an idea?

Comment: are you referencing the config file or really the directory it is located in? Did you try running also with the `--logfile` option to see what it does? See here for a description of all available options: http://doc.owncloud.org/desktop/1.6/advancedusage.html#options

Comment: I'm referencing to the directory and the logfile stays empty.